# Any easy way to maintain one formatter config file for Eclipse and IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

In our team, we use both Intellij and Eclipse. Currently, we are maintaining a eclipse xml file for formatter and using Eclipse Code Formatter in IntelliJ to import it. But one of the issue that I am facing with this approach is, if as a IntelliJ user, I have to make any rule change in formatter, then I can't export the eclipse file from IntelliJ directly. This becomes a problem when we are trying to get into a common standard as a team as every time, I have to make any change, I have to use Eclipse for it.

Any way out for this? Also, I feel there should be one common config file which both can use and export as well. But I can't find any.

Comment: Maybe using EditorConfig as plugin. Both systems provide plugins. To be honest, I've never tried it with Eclipse yet and I'm not sure if they are compatible.

Comment: [Spotless](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless) may fit your needs (it has a Maven plugin and a Gradle plugin).

Comment: Have you tried to use the [eclipse code-formatter inside of intellij](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546-eclipse-code-formatter) ? Both can use the same config file

Comment: Yes, you have to run the Eclipse Java IDE for this task since IntelliJ is shipped with the Eclipse formatter but without providing an UI to edit the formatter profile (same is true for VSCode). Are there any technical problems that prevent you from doing so?

Comment: I spent about a week trying to do exactly what you are trying to do and  for the same reasons. I found that it can't be done. The two IDEs use different rules for formatting and afdter my efforts, I concluded that it was impossible. That's why I now reject the notion that "the dev chooses their own IDE". WRONG! We collectively decide which IDE we're using an we all use that. There are other reasons too - plugins, how-to setup wikis, every work effort around the IDE is doubled, and some are impossible - like formatting, which *must* be the same for all devs otherwise repo diffs are too noisy.

Comment: @Bohemian It's possible since IntelliJ, Eclipse and VSCode Java support have the Eclipse formatter built in. So you can use the same (not only equal, but same) formatting rules. See comment of k3b above.

Comment: may be this helps: https://github.com/google/google-java-format

Comment: I still think _Spotless_, or some other build tool plugin, is your best bet assuming you can't force everyone to use the same IDE. That way the formatting is not tied to the IDE but rather the build tool which everyone will have to use for your project.